TypeError: next expected at least 1 argument, got 0
In the app I have been working on, I made it to have three windows.When I click the button on the first page to open a new window, it tells me a typeerror.I don't understand as I made the function 'next' without any arguments. Here's the code:
    from tkinter import*
    from ttkbootstrap.constants import*
    import ttkbootstrap as tb
    from PIL import Image,ImageTk

    first=tb.Window(themename="cosmo")
    first.geometry("1000x500+180+50")

   # Open an image file
    img = Image.open("C:/Intel/UAM.jpg")
    img_tk = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)

  # Create a label and add the image to it
    first.columnconfigure(0,weight=10)
    first.columnconfigure(1,weight=1)

    pic= tb.Label(first, image=img_tk)
    pic.grid(row=0,column=0,rowspan=3,)

    first_btn=tb.Button(first, text="Next", command=next, bootstyle="primary",width=10)
    first_btn.grid(row=1,column=1,sticky=tb.W)



    def next():

    root=tb.Window(themename="cosmo")

    root.title("UAM Simple Evaluator")
    root.geometry("1000x500+180+50")
    root.lift()

    frame1=tb.Frame(root,bootstyle="light",borderwidth=0)
    frame1.pack(pady=18,padx=18)
    label1=tb.Label(frame1,text="Welcome to UAM Simple Evaluator!", font=("BrushScript", 24),bootstyle=("light,INVERSE"))
    label1.pack(pady=10,padx=10)

    paralabel2="""UAM Simple Evaluator utilizes the uniformly accelerated motion formulas 
    to return users with their desired physical quantities. In order to use it, 
    please input the numerical values of the known variables and 
    enter 'unknown' for the unknown variables below."""
    frame2=tb.Frame(root,bootstyle="light")
    frame2.pack(pady=5,padx=10)
    label2=tb.Label(frame2,text=paralabel2,font=("ComicSans",18),wraplength=900,borderwidth=0,bootstyle=('light,INVERSE'),justify='center')
    label2.pack(pady=10,padx=1,fill="both")
    global frame3
    frame3=tb.Frame(root,bootstyle='light')
    frame3.pack(pady=5,padx=10)               
    frame3.columnconfigure(0,weight=1)
    frame3.columnconfigure(1,weight=8)
    frame3.columnconfigure(4,weight=1)
    frame3.columnconfigure(5,weight=2)                           

    S=tb.StringVar(frame3)
    U=tb.StringVar(frame3)
    V=tb.StringVar(frame3)
    A=tb.StringVar(frame3)
    T=tb.StringVar(frame3)

    S_label=tb.Label(frame3, text="Displacement(m)", font=("Arial", 16))
    S_entry=tb.Entry(frame3, font=("Arial",16),textvariable=S)

    U_label=tb.Label(frame3, text="Initial Velocity(m/s)", font=("Arial", 16))
    U_entry=tb.Entry(frame3, font=("Arial",16),textvariable=U)
                 
    V_label=tb.Label(frame3, text="Final Velocity(m/s)", font=("Arial", 16))
    V_entry=tb.Entry(frame3, font=("Arial",16),textvariable=V)

    A_label=tb.Label(frame3, text="Acceleration(m/s^2)", font=("Arial", 16))
    A_entry=tb.Entry(frame3, font=("Arial",16),textvariable=A)
                 
    T_label=tb.Label(frame3, text="Time(s)", font=("Arial", 16))
    T_entry=tb.Entry(frame3, font=("Arial",16),textvariable=T)

    S_label.grid(row=0,column=0)
    S_entry.grid(row=0,column=1,sticky=tb.W)
    U_label.grid(row=1,column=0)                 
    U_entry.grid(row=1,column=1,sticky=tb.W)                
    V_label.grid(row=2,column=0)
    V_entry.grid(row=2,column=1,sticky=tb.W)
    A_label.grid(row=3,column=0)
    A_entry.grid(row=3,column=1,sticky=tb.W)
    T_label.grid(row=4,column=0)
    T_entry.grid(row=4,column=1,sticky=tb.W)
 

    def UAM_Eval():
     global S
     global U
     global V
     global A
     global T
     if S.get()=='unknown' and A.get()=='unknown':
      S1=((float(U.get())+float(V.get()))*float(T.get()))/2
      A1=(float(V.get())-float(U.get()))/float(T.get())
      S2=round(S1,2)
      A2=round(A1,2)
      print("The value of the distance is",(S2))
      print("The value of the acceleration is",(A2))
    elif S.get()=='unknown' and V.get()=='unknown':
      S3=(float(U.get())*float(T.get()))+((float(A.get())*(float(T.get())**2))/2)
      V1=float(U.get())+(float(A.get())*float(T.get()))
      S4=round(S3,2)
      V2=round(V1,2)
      print("The value of the distance is",S4)
      print("The value of the final velocity is",V2)
    elif S.get()=='unknown' and U.get()=='unknown':
      S5=(float(V.get())*float(T.get()))-(float(A.get())*(float(T.get())**2))/2
      U1='float(V.get())-(float(A.get())*float(T.get()))'
      S6=round(S5,2)
      U2=round(U1,2)
      print("The value of the distance is",S6)
      print("The value of the initial velocity is",U2)
    elif S.get()=='unknown' and T.get()=='unknown':
      S7=((float(V.get())**2)-(float(U.get())**2))/(2*float(A.get()))
      T1=(float(V.get())-float(U.get()))/float(A.get())
      S8=round(S7,2)
      T2=round(T1,2)
      print("The value of the distance is",S8)
      print("The value of the time is",T2)
    elif U.get()=='unknown' and A.get()=='unknown':
      U3=((2*float(S.get()))/float(T.get()))-float(V.get())
      A3=(-2*(float(S.get())-(float(V.get())*float(T.get()))))/(float(T.get())**2)
      U4=round(U2,2)
      A4=round(A2,2)
      print("The value of the initial velocity is",(U4))
      print("The value of the acceleration is",(A4))
    elif U.get()=='unknown' and V.get()=='unknown':
      U5=(float(S.get())-((float(A.get())*(float(T.get())**2))/2))/float(T.get())
      V3=(float(S.get())+((float(A.get())*(float(T.get())**2))/2))/float(T.get())
      U6=round(U5,2)
      V4=round(V3,2)
      print("The value of the initial velocity is",U6)
      print("The value of the final velocity is",V4)
    elif U.get()=='unknown' and T.get()=='unknown':
     U7=((float(V.get())**2)-(2*(float(A.get())*float(S.get()))))**(1/2)
     U8=round(U7,2)
     T3=(float(V.get())-float(U7))/float(A.get())
     T4=round(T3,2)
     print("The value of the initial velocity is",U8)
     print("The value of the time is",T4)
    elif V.get()=='unknown' and A.get()=='unknown':
     V5=((2*float(S.get()))/float(T.get()))-float(U.get())
     A5=((2*(float(S.get())-(float(U.get())*float(T.get())))))/(float(T.get())**2)
     V6=round(V5,2)
     A6=round(A5,2)
     print("The value of the final velocity is",V6)
     print("The value of the acceleration is",A6)
    elif V.get()=='unknown' and T.get()=='unknown':
     V7=((float(U.get())**2)+(2*float(A.get())*float(S.get())))**(1/2)
     V8=round(V7,2)
     T5=(float(V7)-float(U.get()))/float(A.get())
     T6=round(eval(T5),2)
     print("The value of the final velocity is",V8)
     print("The value of the time is",T6)
    elif A.get()=='unknown' and T.get()=='unknown':
     A7=((float(V.get())**2)-(float(U.get())**2))/(2*float(S.get()))
     T7=(2*float(S.get()))/(float(U.get())+float(V.get()))
     A8=round(A7,2)
     T8=round(T7,2)
     print("The value of the acceleration is",A8)
     print("The value of the time is",T8)
    
    def result_printer():
     results_window=tb.Window()
     results_window.geometry("1000x500+180+50")
   
    global result_label
    result=UAM_Eval()
    result_label.config(text=result)
    
    result_frame=tb.Frame(results_window,bootstyle="light")
    result_frame.pack(padx=15,pady=50)
    result_label=tb.Label(result_frame,text="Here is the answer",font=("Arial",18))
    result_label.pack(pady=50,padx=10)
    results_window.mainloop()
    
 
    Calc_btn=tb.Button(frame3, text="Calculate", command=UAM_Eval, width=20,bootstyle="primary")
    result_btn=tb.Button(frame3,text="Next Page",command=result_printer,width=20,bootstyle="info")
    result_label=tb.Label(root,text="Result will be shown here.")
    result_label.pack(padx=10,pady=50)
    Calc_btn.grid(row=5,column=1,rowspan=2,sticky=tb.N)
    result_btn.grid(row=8,column=1,)
    root.mainloop()
    first.mainloop()

What am I missing?
I would love some help.

First, please [edit] your question down to a [mre]. This will help us better understand the problem at hand without having to sift through tons of potentially unrelated code and it might help you narrow down the problem yourself. Second, there seems to be some weird indentation here - I'm not sure if it's just a transcription error or if this is your actual code, but it's worth mentioning.

Please fix your indentation. The body of def next() needs to be indented.

next is the name of a Python built-in function. You're assigning that function when you do command=next, because this is before you've defined your own function. Don't use the same name for your own function.

oh, really? I did not know that.

So, I managed to fix the first problem. The second problem is that whenever I click the button to open the third window, it comes blank.

It is indented in my code, it's when editing it to post here that the indentation was lost.


When I click the button on the first page to open a new window, it
tells me a typeerror

The problem can be fixed.

Don't use Python valid word next. Use some other name, such as
go_next.
Comment out #results_window.mainloop() and #first.mainloop()
Move the tb.Button widget at the end. To prevent an error.

You ready to go.
Snippet: I rearrange code and fix indentation.
from tkinter import*
from ttkbootstrap.constants import*
import ttkbootstrap as tb
from PIL import Image,ImageTk

first=tb.Window(themename="cosmo")
first.geometry("1000x500+180+50")

# Open an image file
img = Image.open(r"C:\Users\Documents\python3_dummy\tmp_dummy\s1.jpg")
img_tk = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)

# Create a label and add the image to it
first.columnconfigure(0,weight=10)
first.columnconfigure(1,weight=1)

pic= tb.Label(first, image=img_tk)
pic.grid(row=0,column=0,rowspan=3,)

 


def go_next():

    root=tb.Window(themename="cosmo")

    root.title("UAM Simple Evaluator")
    root.geometry("1000x500+180+50")
    root.lift()

    frame1=tb.Frame(root,bootstyle="light",borderwidth=0)
    frame1.pack(pady=18,padx=18)
    label1=tb.Label(frame1,text="Welcome to UAM Simple Evaluator!", font=("BrushScript", 24),bootstyle=("light,INVERSE"))
    label1.pack(pady=10,padx=10)

    paralabel2="""UAM Simple Evaluator utilizes the uniformly accelerated motion formulas 
    to return users with their desired physical quantities. In order to use it, 
    please input the numerical values of the known variables and 
    enter 'unknown' for the unknown variables below."""
    frame2=tb.Frame(root,bootstyle="light")
    frame2.pack(pady=5,padx=10)
    label2=tb.Label(frame2,text=paralabel2,font=("ComicSans",18),wraplength=900,borderwidth=0,bootstyle=('light,INVERSE'),justify='center')
    label2.pack(pady=10,padx=1,fill="both")
    global frame3
    frame3=tb.Frame(root,bootstyle='light')
    frame3.pack(pady=5,padx=10)               
    frame3.columnconfigure(0,weight=1)
    frame3.columnconfigure(1,weight=8)
    frame3.columnconfigure(4,weight=1)
    frame3.columnconfigure(5,weight=2)                           

    S=tb.StringVar(frame3)
    U=tb.StringVar(frame3)
    V=tb.StringVar(frame3)
    A=tb.StringVar(frame3)
    T=tb.StringVar(frame3)

    S_label=tb.Label(frame3, text="Displacement(m)", font=("Arial", 16))
    S_entry=tb.Entry(frame3, font=("Arial",16),textvariable=S)

    U_label=tb.Label(frame3, text="Initial Velocity(m/s)", font=("Arial", 16))
    U_entry=tb.Entry(frame3, font=("Arial",16),textvariable=U)
                 
    V_label=tb.Label(frame3, text="Final Velocity(m/s)", font=("Arial", 16))
    V_entry=tb.Entry(frame3, font=("Arial",16),textvariable=V)

    A_label=tb.Label(frame3, text="Acceleration(m/s^2)", font=("Arial", 16))
    A_entry=tb.Entry(frame3, font=("Arial",16),textvariable=A)
                 
    T_label=tb.Label(frame3, text="Time(s)", font=("Arial", 16))
    T_entry=tb.Entry(frame3, font=("Arial",16),textvariable=T)

    S_label.grid(row=0,column=0)
    S_entry.grid(row=0,column=1,sticky=tb.W)
    U_label.grid(row=1,column=0)                 
    U_entry.grid(row=1,column=1,sticky=tb.W)                
    V_label.grid(row=2,column=0)
    V_entry.grid(row=2,column=1,sticky=tb.W)
    A_label.grid(row=3,column=0)
    A_entry.grid(row=3,column=1,sticky=tb.W)
    T_label.grid(row=4,column=0)
    T_entry.grid(row=4,column=1,sticky=tb.W)
 

def UAM_Eval():
    global S
    global U
    global V
    global A
    global T
    if S.get()=='unknown' and A.get()=='unknown':
        S1=((float(U.get())+float(V.get()))*float(T.get()))/2
        A1=(float(V.get())-float(U.get()))/float(T.get())
        S2=round(S1,2)
        A2=round(A1,2)
        print("The value of the distance is",(S2))
        print("The value of the acceleration is",(A2))
    elif S.get()=='unknown' and V.get()=='unknown':
        S3=(float(U.get())*float(T.get()))+((float(A.get())*(float(T.get())**2))/2)
        V1=float(U.get())+(float(A.get())*float(T.get()))
        S4=round(S3,2)
        V2=round(V1,2)
        print("The value of the distance is",S4)
        print("The value of the final velocity is",V2)
    elif S.get()=='unknown' and U.get()=='unknown':
       S5=(float(V.get())*float(T.get()))-(float(A.get())*(float(T.get())**2))/2
       U1='float(V.get())-(float(A.get())*float(T.get()))'
       S6=round(S5,2)
       U2=round(U1,2)
       print("The value of the distance is",S6)
       print("The value of the initial velocity is",U2)
    elif S.get()=='unknown' and T.get()=='unknown':
       S7=((float(V.get())**2)-(float(U.get())**2))/(2*float(A.get()))
       T1=(float(V.get())-float(U.get()))/float(A.get())
       S8=round(S7,2)
       T2=round(T1,2)
       print("The value of the distance is",S8)
       print("The value of the time is",T2)
    elif U.get()=='unknown' and A.get()=='unknown':
       U3=((2*float(S.get()))/float(T.get()))-float(V.get())
       A3=(-2*(float(S.get())-(float(V.get())*float(T.get()))))/(float(T.get())**2)
       U4=round(U2,2)
       A4=round(A2,2)
       print("The value of the initial velocity is",(U4))
       print("The value of the acceleration is",(A4))
    elif U.get()=='unknown' and V.get()=='unknown':
       U5=(float(S.get())-((float(A.get())*(float(T.get())**2))/2))/float(T.get())
       V3=(float(S.get())+((float(A.get())*(float(T.get())**2))/2))/float(T.get())
       U6=round(U5,2)
       V4=round(V3,2)
       print("The value of the initial velocity is",U6)
       print("The value of the final velocity is",V4)
    elif U.get()=='unknown' and T.get()=='unknown':
       U7=((float(V.get())**2)-(2*(float(A.get())*float(S.get()))))**(1/2)
       U8=round(U7,2)
       T3=(float(V.get())-float(U7))/float(A.get())
       T4=round(T3,2)
       print("The value of the initial velocity is",U8)
       print("The value of the time is",T4)
    elif V.get()=='unknown' and A.get()=='unknown':
       V5=((2*float(S.get()))/float(T.get()))-float(U.get())
       A5=((2*(float(S.get())-(float(U.get())*float(T.get())))))/(float(T.get())**2)
       V6=round(V5,2)
       A6=round(A5,2)
       print("The value of the final velocity is",V6)
       print("The value of the acceleration is",A6)
    elif V.get()=='unknown' and T.get()=='unknown':
       V7=((float(U.get())**2)+(2*float(A.get())*float(S.get())))**(1/2)
       V8=round(V7,2)
       T5=(float(V7)-float(U.get()))/float(A.get())
       T6=round(eval(T5),2)
       print("The value of the final velocity is",V8)
       print("The value of the time is",T6)
    elif A.get()=='unknown' and T.get()=='unknown':
       A7=((float(V.get())**2)-(float(U.get())**2))/(2*float(S.get()))
       T7=(2*float(S.get()))/(float(U.get())+float(V.get()))
       A8=round(A7,2)
       T8=round(T7,2)
       print("The value of the acceleration is",A8)
       print("The value of the time is",T8)
    
def result_printer():
    results_window=tb.Window()
    results_window.geometry("1000x500+180+50")

    global result_label
    result=UAM_Eval()
    result_label.config(text=result) 

    result_frame=tb.Frame(results_window,bootstyle="light")
    result_frame.pack(padx=15,pady=50)
    result_label=tb.Label(result_frame,text="Here is the answer",font=("Arial",18))
    result_label.pack(pady=50,padx=10)
    #results_window.mainloop()


    Calc_btn=tb.Button(frame3, text="Calculate", command=UAM_Eval, width=20,bootstyle="primary")
    result_btn=tb.Button(frame3,text="Next Page",command=result_printer,width=20,bootstyle="info")
    result_label=tb.Label(root,text="Result will be shown here.")
    result_label.pack(padx=10,pady=50)
    Calc_btn.grid(row=5,column=1,rowspan=2,sticky=tb.N)
    result_btn.grid(row=8,column=1,)
    root.mainloop()
    #first.mainloop()

first_btn=tb.Button(first, text="Next", command=go_next, bootstyle="primary",width=10)
first_btn.grid(row=1,column=1,sticky=tb.W)

Screenshot:

